# Is there anything like a config reference for Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to know what each 'config' key represents within the usual yaml config (not even sure what it's called) as well as what options / directives are available.

For example what does the following mean:

```
  ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      name: example
```

I could google for 'kubernetes ports', but is there a more accurate way to interpret the various configs keys / values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about reading the [Kubernetes Resources Reference Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/resources-reference/v1.5/#deployment-v1beta1)?

All the directives are defined here for the various resources exploited by Kubernetes. Eg: [ContainerPort v1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/resources-reference/v1.5/#containerport-v1)

Comment: Thanks!  I also mangade to find this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/extensions/v1beta1/definitions/#_v1beta1_deploymentspec

Not too sure what the difference is though

Comment: I think the lattest is about the HTTP API used by applications such as kubectl, while the other is about the resources (ReplicaSets, configmaps, etc.). Do not hesitate to approve if it helped ;-)